# WCF Response Class Best Practices

Tags: wcf

I'm not sure if there's a best practice for Response Message in WCF. Could anyone please guide me to right direction please?

I've a BlaResponse Object with following attributes:

```
1. dateTime
2. sucessfailureMessage.
```

is there anything else I need to add e.g. number of errors, details of errors. Number of success correlationID etc etc?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the requirement for your system, what are you building? Without that context I think we would struggle to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally considered good practice to hide technical details of errors, or any information that discloses details about the server / architecture from the clients (unless you are debugging of course), as this might compromise your security.

It really depends what you are doing, so I don't think I can say what additional info you might need without more information about your implementation. Even the standard [Fault Contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650547.aspx) is pretty much just a wrapper for your own custom data.

Comment: Thanks @Franchesca, the problem is I don't have any specific requirement. I've an operation that does INSERT on to database table using EF. EF INSERT seems to fail whole transaction if one of the data is invalid. Ideally, I would like to send back number of errors and details for each errors

Comment: @flybyte In that case I would just use a strongly typed FaultContract for the method you are calling on the service, catch the exceptions from the insert, put the data into a object of type MyCustomErrorData, and throw a faultException of type MyCustomErrorData. You can design the MyCustomErrorData class to hold everything you need to pass to the client. This is the standard way to pass error information back to the client. [This tutorial](http://www.wcftutorial.net/Fault-Contract.aspx) covers all the basics of setting this up. If you need anything else let me know :)

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have such attributes. You must have some real requirement for introducing these parameters in your response - for example response grouping both successful and failed operations. If your response is just for single operation you should get rid of that and use exceptions for propagating faults.

WCF has very big support for typed exceptions - [FaultContracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733721.aspx). You can create special `FaultContract` type for any expected exception and throw it with typed `FaultException`. Client can catch each expected exception separately and handle it.

Comment: Thanks @Ladislav, the problem is I don't have any specific requirement. I've an operation that does INSERT on to database table using EF. EF INSERT seems to fail whole transaction if one of the data is invalid. Ideally, I would like to send back number of errors and details for each errors

Comment: You will get only first error. EF will not continue in processing when the first command fails. You can simply use exception for that or create a fault as I described.